# Replace text with GLib

Tags: c, glib

I have a string with a ton of `\n`'s, I'd like to turn each of them into `\001\n\001CW1` . What's the easiest way to do this, using glib? No regex, just plain replace.

Comment: Is there anything except `\n`? Do you really want `glib`, not `glibc`?

Comment: No, this is all. Yes, I really am using glib, the thing with `g_free` and stuff.

Comment: Then the answer is too small to post it as answer: strlen(string) / 2; g_malloc enough space, write your sequence in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can easily be done with `g_strsplit` and `g_strjoinv`:

```
char **split = g_strsplit(text, "\n", -1);
g_free(text);
text = g_strjoinv("\001\n\001CW1 ", split);
g_strfreev(split);
```

While this is a very common construct in scripting languages, it's a bit weird to do in C/with glib, but I guess it is the right/only way.

Comment: It's a lot of allocations and frees. However, if you had to solve **only** with glib functions, it's correct.

Comment: I like to think it knows to allocate efficiently.

Comment: [That's a big assumption](https://github.com/GNOME/glib/blob/2dce3ce125cd0a58d4f49517dcd451857d62bdbd/glib/gstrfuncs.c#L2324)

Comment: Ah yeah I asked the developers turns out it's pretty inefficient. Maybe one day we'll have a g_fast_strsplit or something. It's not a big deal, and it's no worse than using a scripting language, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

g_string_replace is implemented since version 2.68:

https://docs.gtk.org/glib/method.String.replace.html

Comment: The chosen implementation, `g_string_replace()`, was actually released in GLib 2.68.0 in March 2021.